# Best Approach for maintaining 'users in country' count MySql

Tags: mysql

Given a series of complex websites that all use the same user tacking mysql database.  (this is not our exact situation:  but a simplification of the situation to make this post a brief/efficient as possible)

We don't always know where a user is when he starts using a site.  In fact there are about 50 points in the code where the country field might get updated.  We might collect it from the IP address on use.   We might get it when he uses his credit card.  We might get it when he fills out a form.  Heck we might get it when we talk to him on the phone.

Assume a simple structure like:

```
CREATE  TABLE `Users` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `County` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );
```

What Im wondering is what is the best way to keep track of one more scrap of information on this person:

```
   `Number_of_Users_in_My_Country`.
```

I know I could run a simple query to get it with each record.  But I constantly need two other bits of information:  (Keep in mind that Im not really dealing with countries but other groups that number in the 100,000X : again: counties is just to make this post simple)

1. User count by Country and
2. Selection of countries with less than x users.

Im wondering if I should create a trigger when the country value changes to update the Number_of_Users_in_My_Country field?

As Im new to mySQL I would love to know thoughts on this or any other approach.

Comment: If you want a column with the amount of total users on a given group, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having the above table created? Since you could rather create a table called `country,total_users` and each time a user joins a group or whatever you increase/decrease the numbers there instead.

Comment: @PRix   Im sorry I probably didn't give you enough information.  We track users as they visit.  We keep lots of other data on them.  (Number of visits via cookie,  browser type,  pages visited etc).  When an event that lets us know the county fires:  we then update that users "Country' field.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people will tell you not to do that, because it's not normalized.  However, if it's trivial to keep an aggregate value (to save complex joins in certain queries), I'd say go for it.  Keep in mind with your triggers that you can't update the same table as the trigger's definition, so be careful in defining how certain events propagate updates to other tables, lest you get in a loop.

An additional recommendation: I would keep a table for countries, and use a foreign key reference from Users to Countries.  Then in countries, have a column for total users in that country.  Users_in_my_country seems to have a very specific use, and it would be easier to maintain from the countries' perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've simplified the question somewhat, it's hard to be totally precise.

In general, if at all possible, I prefer to calculate these derived values on the fly. And to find out if it's valuable, I prefer to try it out; 100.000x records is not a particularly scary number, and I'd much prefer to spend time tuning a query/indexing scheme once than dealing with maintenance crazy for the life of the application.

If you've tried that, and still can't get it to work, my next consideration would be to work with stale/cached data. It all depends on your business, but if it's okay for the "number of users in my country" value to be slightly out of date, then calculating these values and caching them in the application layer would be much better. Caching has lots of pre-existing libraries you can use, it's well understood by most developers, and with high traffic web sites, caching for even a few seconds can have a dramatic effect on your performance and scalability. Alternatively, have a script that populates a table "country_usercount" and run it every minute or so.

If the data must, absolutely, be fresh, I'd include the logic to update the counts in the application layer code - it's a bit ugly, but it's easy to debug, and behaves predictably. So, every time the event fires that tells you which country the user is from, you update the country_usercount table from the application code.

The reason I dislike triggers is that they can lead to horrible, hard to replicate bugs and performance issues - if you have several of those aggregated pre-calculated fields, and you write a trigger for each, you could easily end up with lots of unexpected database activity.